# sql server 2008 Anonymous login failure

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, authentication, iis-7.5

First, let me say that I have spent the last two days researching this problem on this site as well as others, obviously without result. So on to the problem:

I have moved a website and database from my old 32 bit machine to a new 64 bit machine. Both are configured as follows:

Windows 7 Ultimate N
SQL Server 2008 R2
IIS 7.5

The database uses SQL Server Authentication

In the web.config file:

Database connection string:
 `<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PEYCO\;Initial Catalog=CatalogName;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=0" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

IIS has Anonymous Authentication enabled. The website on both machines are configured the same. I can access the website from both machines without problem. However, when I go to pages that require the user to be logged in, the error occurs.

In both cases, the database and iis are located on the same machine. I am able to access tables and stored procedures from the management console without problems.

The original machine works correctly, but the new one gives the above error when running code-behind that accesses the database. Logins work correctly. I have probably tried every combination of settings possible, and still the problem persists.

Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

PS: I should also add that I have tried this connection string" `<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PEYCO;Initial Catalog=Name;Integrated Security=false;uid=sa;pwd=MyPwd;Connect Timeout=0;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The application on IIS runs under application pool. This application pool is run under some user account, default is IIS APPPOOL\DEFAULTAPPPOOL. This user (or other if you have set it otherwise) is trying to connect to the database but has no permissions to do so. Therefore you receive an error.

You need to allow this user to connect to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was router related. There are multiple computers running and the port was being routed to the wrong computer. (Banging head against wall...)